# Error using train() : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, r-caret, training-data

I looked at the other posted questions regarding this issue but was not successful to make my code work.

Here is my code:

```
library(titanic)  
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(rpart)

# 3 significant digits
options(digits = 3)

# clean the data
titanic_clean <- titanic_train %>%
  mutate(Survived = factor(Survived),
         Embarked = factor(Embarked),
         Age = ifelse(is.na(Age), median(Age, na.rm = TRUE), Age), # NA age to median age
         FamilySize = SibSp + Parch + 1) %>%    # count family members
  select(Survived,  Sex, Pclass, Age, Fare, SibSp, Parch, FamilySize, Embarked)

index <- createDataPartition(titanic_clean$Survived, times = 1, p = 0.2, list = FALSE)
test_set <- titanic_clean[index, ]
train_set <- titanic_clean[-index, ]

caret::train(train_set$Survived ~ train_set$Fare, method="glm", data=train_set)
```

The train function returns the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Any ideas?

Comment: when you provide the data and a formula, you don't need to explicitly call the column, so do ```train(Survived ~ Fare, method="glm", data=train_set)```

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf, that solved it.

Comment: A follow up; if I run predict([output from train], data=test_set) I get the following error message: 'newdata' had 179 rows but variables found have 712 rows?

Comment: the argument is ```newdata=``` rather than ```data=...```